# Python: multiprocessing.map: If one process raises an exception, why aren't other processes' finally blocks called?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, try-catch-finally

My understanding is that finally clauses *must* *always* be executed if the try has been entered.

```python
import random

from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import sleep

def Process(x):
  try:
    print x
    sleep(random.random())
    raise Exception('Exception: ' + x)
  finally:
    print 'Finally: ' + x

Pool(3).map(Process, ['1','2','3'])
```

Expected output is that for each of x which is printed on its own by line 8, there *must* be an occurrence of 'Finally x'.

Example output:

```
$ python bug.py 
1
2
3
Finally: 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bug.py", line 14, in <module>
    Pool(3).map(Process, ['1','2','3'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 225, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 522, in get
    raise self._value
Exception: Exception: 2
```

It seems that an exception terminating one process terminates the parent and sibling processes, even though there is further work *required* to be done in other processes.

Why am I wrong? Why is this correct? If this is correct, how *should* one safely clean up resources in multiprocess Python?

Comment: Just a heads up for others, this exact code (with print statements fixed for Python 3) on Python 3.6 correctly executes all finally blocks before the parent process reraises the exception.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Short answer: `SIGTERM` trumps `finally`.**

Long answer: Turn on logging with `mp.log_to_stderr()`:

```
import random
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import logging

logger=mp.log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)

def Process(x):
    try:
        logger.info(x)
        time.sleep(random.random())
        raise Exception('Exception: ' + x)
    finally:
        logger.info('Finally: ' + x)

result=mp.Pool(3).map(Process, ['1','2','3'])
```

The logging output includes:

```
[DEBUG/MainProcess] terminating workers
```

Which corresponds to this code in `multiprocessing.pool._terminate_pool`:

```
    if pool and hasattr(pool[0], 'terminate'):
        debug('terminating workers')
        for p in pool:
            p.terminate()
```

Each `p` in `pool` is a `multiprocessing.Process`, and calling `terminate` (at least on non-Windows machines) calls SIGTERM:

from `multiprocessing/forking.py`:

```
class Popen(object)
    def terminate(self):
        ...
            try:
                os.kill(self.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
            except OSError, e:
                if self.wait(timeout=0.1) is None:
                    raise
```

**So it comes down to what happens when a Python process in a `try` suite is sent a `SIGTERM`.**

Consider the following example (test.py):

```
import time    
def worker():
    try:
        time.sleep(100)        
    finally:
        print('enter finally')
        time.sleep(2) 
        print('exit finally')    
worker()
```

If you run it, then send it a `SIGTERM`, then the process ends immediately, without entering the `finally` suite, as evidenced by no output, and no delay.

In one terminal:

```
% test.py
```

In second terminal:

```
% pkill -TERM -f "test.py"
```

Result in first terminal:

```
Terminated
```

Compare that with what happens when the process is sent a `SIGINT` (`C-c`):

In second terminal:

```
% pkill -INT -f "test.py"
```

Result in first terminal:

```
enter finally
exit finally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/unutbu/pybin/test.py", line 14, in <module>
    worker()
  File "/home/unutbu/pybin/test.py", line 8, in worker
    time.sleep(100)        
KeyboardInterrupt
```

**Conclusion: `SIGTERM` trumps `finally`.**

Answer (score 5):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7703607/1843746) from [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu) definitely explains *why* you get the behavior you observe. However, it should emphasized that SIGTERM is sent only because of how `multiprocessing.pool._terminate_pool` is implemented. If you can avoid using `Pool`, then you can get the behavior you desire. Here is a [borrowed example](http://jtushman.github.io/blog/2014/01/14/python-%7C-multiprocessing-and-interrupts/):

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep
import random

def f(x):
    try:
        sleep(random.random()*10)
        raise Exception
    except:
        print "Caught exception in process:", x
        # Make this last longer than the except clause in main.
        sleep(3)
    finally:
        print "Cleaning up process:", x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes = []
    for i in range(4):
        p = Process(target=f, args=(i,))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    try:
        for process in processes:
            process.join()
    except:
        print "Caught exception in main."
    finally:
        print "Cleaning up main."
```

After sending a SIGINT is, example output is:

```
Caught exception in process: 0
^C
Cleaning up process: 0
Caught exception in main.
Cleaning up main.
Caught exception in process: 1
Caught exception in process: 2
Caught exception in process: 3
Cleaning up process: 1
Cleaning up process: 2
Cleaning up process: 3
```

Note that the `finally` clause is ran for all processes. If you need shared memory, consider using `Queue`, `Pipe`, `Manager`, or some external store like `redis` or `sqlite3`.

Answer (score 1):

`finally` re-raises the original exception [unless you `return` from it](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement). The exception is then raised by `Pool.map` and kills your entire application. The subprocesses are terminated and you see no other exceptions.

You can add a `return` to swallow the exception:

```
def Process(x):
  try:
    print x
    sleep(random.random())
    raise Exception('Exception: ' + x)
  finally:
    print 'Finally: ' + x
    return
```

Then you should have `None` in your `map` result when an exception occurred.

Comment: This is a useful workaround, but surely in any case the runtime shouldn't be allowed to be killed until all finally blocks have been run?

Comment: @Daniel Wagner-Hall: `Pool.map` is modeled after `map`, which also terminates when the function mapped raises an exception. Maybe (try it out) the child processes are terminated normally and actually do execute the `finally` - only because your main thread is killed first the output from the children is not read anymore.